# Image and text with opacity background in the same DIV

Tags: css, html, background, opacity

I'm trying to make an image and text with an opacity!

Background appear in the same div without using the image as background. How can I make this work?

Kindly see image:

[image]

Comment: use **relative** position to __wrapper div__ and **absolute** position for children (__img__, __div__ and __text__)

Comment: Asked 4 questions and 0 accepted??

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
  <span>Title</span>
  <img src="" />
</div>

div{
  position: relative;
}
span{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: is there also a way to make the span the same width as the image automatically?

Comment: There is! You need to use jquery to calculate image width and apply the same to span

Comment: @Dipaks you don't need JQuery for that - just add `right: 0` to your span CSS

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Please post a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/. Let me see how this is possible with right: 0; 'is there also a way to make the span the same width as the image automatically? '

Comment: @Myheadhurts check now - http://jsfiddle.net/dipaks2011/fbAed/1/ You can call it a trick to make it work by making DIV inline-block :)

Comment: @Dipaks I wouldn't really call it a trick, I would call it the correct way to do it. It is complete overkill to pull in a JQuery library to achieve such a simple layout :) But we can agree to disagree ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* RGBa with 0.5 opacity */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

For rgba the last field is the opacity. It's not fully supported in some older IE versions though so the only fully cross browser method at the moment is to use a transparent image as the background.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to write HTML:

```
<figure>
    <img src="/image.jpg">
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
</figure>
```

After that you only have to write CSS: example:

```
figure {
  position: relative;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3); // or transparent gif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,50);` the background will be black and semi-transparent.

It won't affect the transparency of the text because to set the transparency of the text, it's `color:rgba(255,255,255,50);` If you don't write that, the text won't be semi-transparent.