# display text and image at the same time : Opacity of background

Tags: image, css, background, opacity

Sorry, May be my tone is not good,

**Question:**

I am using CSS3 code of **opacity background** like this

**Edit:** (adding code)

CSS:

```
opecity {
   opacity:.75; 
   content:('Hello');
   background:#111 url(../img/view.png) no-repeat center;
} 
.opecity img:hover{
   -moz-opacity: 0.10;
  opacity: 0.10;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=70);
   background:#000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="opecity">
  <a class="example-image-link" href="img/port1.png" data-lightbox="example-1">
     <img class="example-image" src="img/port1.png" alt="thumb-1" width="250" height="220"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

This code display image only, but not display content 'Hello'. But I want to display image and content together at the same time. I also concern with this
**Stackoweflow.com question**.

[Image and text with opacity background in the same DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260324/image-and-text-with-opacity-background-in-the-same-div)

But I don't get solution.

Comment: it could be your browser, can you please show us part of the code?(HTML)

Comment: its css code .opecity {
 opacity:.75; content:('Hello'); background:#111 url(../img/view.png) no-repeat center;
 }
.opecity img:hover{
   -moz-opacity: 0.10;
opacity: 0.10;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=70);
background:#000;
 }

Comment: Its  HTML Code: <div class="opecity"> <a class="example-image-link" href="img/port1.png" data-lightbox="example-1"><img class="example-image" src="img/port1.png" alt="thumb-1" width="250" height="220"/></a></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First line, You've `opecity {` and you should use `.opecity` because it's a class.
- Separate the Content and place it in his own `.classs {}`

I.E:

```
.example-image-link:hover:after {
 content:'Hello';
}
```

- It wont work if you use it before or after the image class (Try This)

> <\div class="opecity">
>
> <\a class="example-image-link" href="img/port1.png"
>   data-lightbox="example-1"> <\img class="example-image"
>   src="http://humor.desvariandoando.com/wp-content/uploads/susto.jpg"
>   alt="thumb-1" width="250" height="220"/>  </div>
>
> .example-image-link:hover:after {  content:'Hello'; }

remove the `\` and change `.example-image-link:hover:after` for `img:hover:after`

- The link that you posted they used another method:

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>

div{
  position: relative;
}
span{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
}
</style>

<div>
  <span>Title</span>
  <img src="http://humor.desvariandoando.com/wp-content/uploads/susto.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(I took it from your link)

you can test all the html and css here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp): "The content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content."

Try

```
.opecity:after {
    content:'Hello';
}
```